# Having issues with the falling edge capture

Tags: verilog

for each bit in a 32-bit vector, capture when the input signal changes from 1 in one clock cycle to 0 the next. "Capture" means that the output will remain 1 until the register is reset (synchronous reset).

Each output bit behaves like a SR flip-flop: The output bit should be set (to 1) the cycle after a 1 to 0 transition occurs. The output bit should be reset (to 0) at the positive clock edge when reset is high. If both of the above events occur at the same time, reset has precedence. In the last 4 cycles of the example waveform below, the 'reset' event occurs one cycle earlier than the 'set' event, so there is no conflict here.

I tried solving this:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [31:0] in,
    output [31:0] out
);
reg [31:0] q;
reg [31:0] out1;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    q <= in;
end

always @(*) begin
    out1 = ~in & q;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset)
        out <= 0;
     else begin
         if (out1) 
             out <= out1;
     end
end

endmodule
```

The output gets replaced everytime. Its not able to old the old value and update the new bits. 
Any idea how to modify this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `if`. That `if` looks at the total vector but, what I understand from your description, you want to operate on a per-bit basis.

```
integer b;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (reset)
        out <= 0;
     else
     begin
        for (b=0; b<8; b=b+1)
           if (out1[b]) 
               out[b] <= out1[b];
     end
end
```

(If my understanding is wrong I will be happy to delete my answer :-)

Answer (score -1):

I also attempted the same problem and I managed to complete the code. Whether or not this is synthesizable, I'm not sure because I'm newish to verilog but here's my code:

```
module top_module (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input [31:0] in,
    output [31:0] out
);
    reg [31:0] dlast;
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        dlast <= in;
        if(reset) begin
            out <= 32'd0;
        end
        else begin
            if((~in & dlast)!==32'd0) begin
                out <= (~in & dlast) | out; 
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: if you're not going to reset dlast, you should move it into its own always block. even if your code does synthesize, it is highly unconventional.

Comment: What does moving it into it's own always block do?